# Windows 7 PC very slow when accessing a MYSQL DB on a windows server machine

Tags: mysql, windows

I am testsing on Windows 7 in preparation for our departments upgrade from XP to WIn 7.

All nine XP PCs access a MySQl DB on a Windows Server machine with no problems.

However on the Windows 7 PC the SQL queries run very slow.

As a comparison running the same SELECT on XP and win 7.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

XP 3414 rows returned in 0.06 sec

WIN 7  3414 rows returned in 5.26 sec

Different applications have the same problem ( Python apps, VB6 .exes, and various mysqlDB GUIs )

All the PCs ( XP and Win7 ) have McAfee but the settings cannot be changed.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve the performance?

Comment: are the query plan, mysql server version, mysql database engine identical?

Comment: Have you tried running the application on compatibility mode and selecting windows xp ? If it improves performance then that might be a solution, if not it might just be the different way the networks stack works in windows 7 compared to xp.

Comment: Did you try with another machine with windows 7? perhaps is a problem with this particular machine

Comment: Also what version of windows server are you using , if it is 2003 try using 2008 with the windows 7 pc's .

Comment: I have added the Windows 7 PC details to the hosts file on the server ande vice-versa  with no improvement

Comment: I tried compatability mode and running as administrator   neither has helped

Comment: I have tried with a different windows 7 Machine  still the same problems.  The Server is 2003 I'll see if I can get this upgraded

Comment: Ok cool did you try running the app in compatibility mode ?

Comment: Thanks for the responses  It loks like server 2003 is where the problem lies. I couldn't get a server 2008 machine but moved the DB to an XP machine and everything is much quicker

Comment: @eis query plan can't change for an FULL table scan... most logical would be slower disks or lots off I/O read or 1/O writes on the machine... but most likly you are connecting with "localhost" try with "127.0.0.1" instead

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the application on compatibility mode and selecting windows xp ?

If it improves performance then that might be a solution, if not it might just be the

different way the networks stack works in windows 7 compared to xp.

Try moving the db from the 2003 pc to a windows server 2008 box.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment (remove '#') the line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

In the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` file (anti-virus may block it - if so, turn it off for a second).

Answer (score -1):

It may have other causes but for me setting on my.ini the param 
mysqld skip-name-resolve
solved the problem more than one time.